# Get return value of a command

Tags: php

I've found many ways to run a command, like `exec`,`system`,`shell_exec`, but they all seem to return the command output.

I want only the return value (integer).

How can I do that?

```
<?php
$retval = something("script.sh");
```

Comment: What's wrong with the third argument for [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)? `exec('script.sh', $output, $retval);`

Comment: What's wrong with the second argument for [system()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) `system('script.sh', $retval);`

Comment: good answers, I looked at the docs but somehow missed this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exec()`

```
exec("command", $output, $retval);
echo "output: $output\n";
echo "return value: $retval\n";
```

`exec()` consumes `$output` and `$retval` by reference and their values will be set inside of `exec()`. [Check the manual of `exec()` again.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Btw, `$output` and `$retval` will get implicitly initialized, they don't need to exist before the `exec()` call.